# heat-client won't run, No module named utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, heat, openstack-heat

I'm trying to get the heat-client up and running on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I've followed instructions from:

http://docs.rackspace.com/orchestration/api/v1/orchestration-getting-started/content/Install_Heat_Client.html

But when I enter heat stack-list to test I receive the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/heat", line 7, in <module>
    from heatclient.shell import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/heatclient/shell.py", line 26, in <module>
    from oslo.utils import encodeutils
ImportError: No module named utils`

I've tried re-installing python2.7-dev, re-installed setup utilities, checked that my ~/.profile had:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by doing: `sudo apt-get remove python-pip
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py`

Found the solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991